# Delaying a string function?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So basically I all my code is within a while loop. Within that I have a for loop which checks for a bee in the neighboruging grids. When it detects a bee it calls a function. I need all the functions called by that to wait and only run when the while loop is just about to be finsihed (outside the for loop but inside the while loop).

Here is my code:

```
Cell.prototype.floodFillEach = function() {
  grid[orginalX][orginalY].floodFill();
  while(repeat<=7){
    for (var xoff = 0-x12; xoff <= 0+x12; xoff++) {
      for (var yoff = 0; yoff <= 0+x12; yoff++) {
        var i = orginalX + xoff;
        var j = orginalY + yoff;
        if (i > -1 && i < cols && j > 0 && j < rows) {
          var neighbour = grid[i][j];
          if (neighbour.marked2) {
            console.log("x:"+i+"  y:"+j);
            neighbour.floodFill(); // everytime this function is called within this while loop i need it to wait untill...       
          }
        }
      }
    }
      // ... here. I need the functions called to wait and run here and after they are done only then proceed with the rest of this while loop
    x12++
    repeat++
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store in an array, then call at the end.

```js
Cell.prototype.floodFillEach = function() {
  grid[orginalX][orginalY].floodFill();
  while(repeat<=7){
    const neighboursToFloodFill = [];
    for (var xoff = 0-x12; xoff <= 0+x12; xoff++) {
      for (var yoff = 0; yoff <= 0+x12; yoff++) {
        var i = orginalX + xoff;
        var j = orginalY + yoff;
        if (i > -1 && i < cols && j > 0 && j < rows) {
          var neighbour = grid[i][j];
          if (neighbour.marked2) {
            console.log("x:"+i+"  y:"+j);
            neighboursToFloodFill.push(neighbour);     
          }
        }
      }
    }
    for (const neighbour of neighboursToFloodFill) {
      neighbour.floodFill();
    }
    x12++
    repeat++
  }
}
```